# Creating New Column then Receiving 'Invalid Column Name' Error

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I'm adding a column to a table with the following script

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user]
ADD username varchar(20);
```

I successfully execute that command and confirm that the new column is added to the existing user table.
However, I'm then running a script to create a stored procedure that inserts into this new field and I'm receiving an error claiming that the field does not exist.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[add_user]
    @username varchar(20)
AS

begin
set nocount on;

INSERT INTO user (username)
VALUES (@username)
```

I receive the error "Invalid column name 'username'." even though I already confirmed that the column 'username' was added to the user table.

Comment: Perhaps the stored procedure needs to be recompiled.  I would expect SQL Server to do this when it sees that the table is changed, but perhaps it did not.

Comment: How do I recompile it? I even tried restarting Management Studio and still get the error.

Comment: . . You can drop and recreate he procedure to the original code.  Or for more options:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: Did you put a GO after creating your new column? There are cases when you change the structure within the stored procedure, the stored procedure might still give an error because of the existing table structure before execution. This might however not be the case.

Comment: Are you connected to the correct database that you added the column to the table?